# Cloud Dataflow: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no evaluator registered for GroupedValues

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm getting the following exception when running the pipeline locally. There is no exception when submitting for cloud execution.

Thanks,
Genady

```
INFO: Executing pipeline using the DirectPipelineRunner.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: no evaluator registered for GroupedValues [GroupedValues]
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.visitTransform(DirectPipelineRunner.java:606)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:200)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:196)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:109)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:204)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:583)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:327)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:70)
at app.Main.main(Main.java:124)
```

The code outline is basically this:

```
PCollection<KV<MyKey, Iterable<MyValue>>> groupedByMyKey = ...
PCollection<KV<MyKey, MyAggregated>> aggregated = groupedByMyKey.apply(
        Combine.<MyKey, MyValue, MyAggregated>groupedValues(new Aggregator()));
```

Aggregator class extends `CombineFn<MyValue, List<MyValue>, MyAggregated>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share a code snippet that triggers this? GroupedValues is a PTransform that is often used within various combining transforms, so it might be from using something like Min, Max, etc.

The error means that the DirectPipelineRunner doesn't know how to evaluate a GroupedValues. However, that's unexpected, since that should have been expanded into a ParDo before execution.

Comment: I added the two relevant lines for this issue. If that does not help, I can try extracting a small working snippet that triggers it.

Comment: Sorry, I played around for a bit with that code and can't reproduce it. Can you send a complete snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason to this behaviour

I was using a command line argument to run it in remote mode (`--runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner`) and then forced it to run locally with

```java
PipelineRunner<?> runner = DirectPipelineRunner.fromOptions(options);
runner.run(p);
```

After removing these lines and just using the `--runner=DirectPipelineRunner` argument it worked as expected.

Comment: I'm guessing pipeline 'p' was created with options that included another runner (presumably from commandline args), so it can't be run with 'runner'. In fact, users shouldn't really call runner.run() at all. I'll try to get it to throw a clear error in that case, and make sure it's documented clearly.

Comment: I had     `Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);`